# ¿Cómo expresar en español "all over the place" para indicar ideas incoherentes o poco estructuradas?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-modismo

"All over the place" es una frase idiomática para expresar que algo carece de orden y estructura. Básicamente, alude a lo *disperso* de lo que se quiere explicar.

Por ejemplo, si yo redactase una publicación y empezase explicando una idea, pero luego me fuese por las ramas con otras ideas pero de vez en cuando volviese a lo principal y en vez de estructurar con claridad lo que quiero expresar pareciesen varias ideas en el mismo saco, alguien podría decir que en mi publicación mis ideas están "all over the place".

Una traducción literal como (estar) "por todas partes" puede servir en muchos de los contextos, especialmente si nos referimos a objetos físicos. Sin embargo, cuando el uso es más simbólico o referido a conceptos abstractos esa traducción puede no funcionar tan bien. Por ejemplo:

- I'm really distracted lately. My thoughts are *all over the place*
- I didn't like his essay. His ideas were *all over the place*

¿Existe una frase idiomática equivalente en español a "all over the place" para indicar que ideas o conceptos son incoherentes, poco claros, dispersos, etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En cuanto a frases que pueden comunicar el sentido, tanto literal como figurado, de "estar algo por todas partes", me viene a la mente especialmente una:

> **[sin ton ni son](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=ton)**.
>
> 1. locs. advs. coloqs. Sin motivo, ocasión o causa, o fuera de orden y medida. U. t. c. locs. adjs.

Usándola en tus ejemplos:

- Estoy muy distraída últimamente. Mis pensamientos van *sin ton ni son*.
- No me gustó su ensayo. Ponía sus ideas *sin ton ni son*.

Otras expresiones válidas son: "**[sin orden ni concierto](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=orden)**" (definición al final de todo), "**[al tuntún](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=avQA4Jd)**" o, ya estirando un poco, "[ir de aquí para allá](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=aqu%C3%AD)".

En cuanto a palabras, se podrían usar: **[desordenado](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=DF6bgCQ)**, **[desperdigado](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=DKo7MvH)**, o incluso **[esturreado](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=esturreado)**.

---

Respecto a lo indicado en otras respuestas sobre Ⓧ"irse por las ramas", **no me convence**, pues tiene un significado bastante especifico que no tiene por que implicar desorden:

> Ⓧ **[irse alguien por las ramas](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=rama)**.
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Detenerse en lo menos sustancial de un asunto, dejando lo más importante.

Comment: (+1) It has an informal air in English so your first suggestion seems to capture its essence.

Answer (score 3):

Quizá pueda servir la expresión ***ir por las ramas***. En cuyo caso las frases quedarían:

- Estoy muy distraído ultimamente, mis pensamientos se van por las ramas (En este caso suena no muy bien)
- No me gusta su ensayo. Sus ideas se van por las ramas (Suena algo mejor acá)

Es la primera idea que se me viene y que suena lógica aunque no se sea la mejor...

Comment: Esa expresión ya la usa @Diego en su pregunta, aún así creo que es la expresión que mejor encaja. Lo que no sé es si las ideas pueden irse por las ramas, lo normal es usarlo con la persona: **irse _alguien_ por las ramas**

Answer (score 3):

Algunas expresiones que se me ocurren para decir lo mismo que "all over the place" son::

- Las ideas están **desperdigadas** por el texto/documento/parrafo/post

"Irse por las ramas" también puede decirse como:

- **Irse por los cerros de Úbeda** ([significado](https://www.muyinteresante.es/cultura/arte-cultura/articulo/ide-donde-viene-la-expresion-qirse-por-los-cerros-de-ubedaq))
- **No ir al grano**

Answer (score 3):

La palabra divagar tiene tres acepciones en el DLE, dos de las cuales podrían utilizarse con el sentido que buscas:

> **[divagar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E0Vu0uB)**
>
> 2. intr. Separarse del asunto de que se trata.
> 3. intr. Hablar o escribir sin concierto ni propósito fijo y determinado.

La acepcion 2 es similar a *irse por las ramas*, *salirse por peteneras*, salirse del asunto principal y la 3 se relaciona más con las expresiones que propone @walen: *sin ton ni son, sin orden ni concierto, al tuntún*, etc.

Usándolo en tus frase sería algo así:

- Estoy muy distraído últimamente. Divago mucho.
- No me gustó su ensayo. Divagaba demasiado.

Answer (score 3):

Por animarme a dar otra respuesta, yo haré énfasis en una opción que ya se plantea en la propia pregunta: **disperso**.

> **[disperso, sa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DxMkRyL)**
>
> Del lat. *dispersus*, part. pas. de *dispergĕre* 'esparcir, desparramar'.
>
> 1. adj. Que está dispersado. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.

Nótese lo de que se aplica a personas. En cuanto a "dispersado", la acepción que nos ocupa es la segunda:

> **[dispersar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DxI3tTs)**
>
> 2. tr. Dividir el esfuerzo, la atención o la actividad, aplicándolos desordenadamente en múltiples direcciones.

Creo que la palabra "disperso" evoca en la mente del lector lo mismo que "all over the place", que da una sensación de "desperdigado". Así, tus ejemplos quedarían así:

> Me distraigo mucho ultimamente, mis pensamientos andan **dispersos**.
>   No me gustó su ensayo. Sus ideas estaban **dispersas**.

Comment: Disperso, desestructurado...

Answer (score 1):

La traducción básica, pero exactamente equivalente:

***desorganizado***

***sin estructura***

> Estoy muy distraída últimamente. Mis pensamientos están súper desorganizados.
>
> No me gustó su ensayo. Puso sus ideas sin estructura alguna.

Un ejemplo extra, tomada de alguien de mi familia:

> This evening M was overtired and was all over the place.  He's finally fallen asleep.  I'm exhausted.
>
> Hoy M se cansó demasiado, y a la hora de acostarse no se podía calmar.  Cada tres segundos quería emprender otro proyecto.  Ahora ya se durmió.  Estoy agotado/a.