# ¿Se escribe el punto de "etc." si va antes de un signo de cierre de interrogación o de exclamación?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, abreviaturas

Leyendo la pregunta de Diego [¿Cómo expresar en español "all over the place" para indicar ideas incoherentes o poco estructuradas?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22090/1674) me topé con la parte:

> ¿Existe una frase idiomática equivalente en español a "all over the place" para indicar que ideas o conceptos son incoherentes, poco claros, dispersos, **etc?**

La parte que me hizo dudar es la última: estoy acostumbrado a ver *etcétera* abreviado como *etc**.***, con el punto al final, por lo que habría escrito:

> ¿Existe una frase idiomática equivalente en español a "all over the place" para indicar que ideas o conceptos son incoherentes, poco claros, dispersos, **etc.?**

Sin embargo, también es cierto que antes de los signos de interrogación o exclamación no se pone un punto. El DPD en [*Interrogación y exclamación (signos de)*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bH8aKhoE1D6eF5Wp4C) habla del *después*:

> Tras los signos de cierre puede colocarse cualquier signo de puntuación, salvo el punto.

En su artículo sobre el [*punto*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=PxrAnmVfND6FK0uGdT) habla otra vez del *después*:

> 3.3. Si el punto de una abreviatura coincide con el punto de cierre del enunciado, solo debe escribirse un punto, nunca dos: *A la boda fueron todos sus parientes: tíos, primos, sobrinos, etc. Fueron en total ciento veinte invitados.*

Y curiosamente hablando de otros temas utiliza *etc.* seguido de una coma:

> 5.2. Aunque todavía es práctica común en los números escritos con cifras separar los millares, millones, **etc.**, (...)

Pero sigo sin encontrar referencia concreta al caso de *etc.* u otros similares que pudiera haber. ¿Cómo se escribe pues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según el DPD:

> **[abreviatura](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=abreviatura)**.
>
> **6. Ortografía**
>
> d) Se escribe siempre punto detrás de las abreviaturas, salvo: (...) aquellas en las que el punto se sustituye por una barra (...); las abreviaturas que van entre paréntesis (...); las abreviaturas que llevan letras voladas, en las que el punto se escribe delante de estas (...); las abreviaturas que coinciden con final de oración o de párrafo (...). **Los otros signos de puntuación (coma, punto y coma, puntos suspensivos, signo de interrogación, etc.) sí deben escribirse tras el punto de la abreviatura** (...).

De lo cual se entiende que **sí**: en el caso de interrogaciones y exclamaciones, aunque la abreviatura sea la última palabra antes del signo de cierre, se debe escribir el punto igualmente, sea "etc." o cualquier otra.

He resumido mucho el párrafo del DPD porque es bastante largo, pero todos los ejemplos y demás se pueden consultar ahí.